# Maximum records for MAS 500 API stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures

This may be slightly off topic, but I cannot think of a better stack site to put this on so let me know if there is one.

I am using the MAS 500 ERP system's APIs to move invoices into the accounting system. It seems that the API will not process more than 3 invoices at a time. I pull my test data from a table with 9 invoices in it. They all get staged successfully with the same session key, however, when I run the stored proc to put them in the system, only 3 go through. The other 6 do not fail, they simply are not processed at all. I could call the procedure for every invoice(or every 3), but its expensive at about 10 seconds a call. Is there some sort of max on how many invoices can be processed per call? Could it really be only 3? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a pretty crappy design, but I found a line in the documentation that says to put a while loop around the call where the condition is oContinue. oContinue returns 1 if it has more records to process and 0 if not. Talk about a sloppy API...

Answer (score 1):

I work with MAS90/200, so I can't help with your problem, but you might try posting in Sage's forum: http://community.sagemas.com/sagemas/?category.id=SageMAS500DiscussionForums